# Не получается изменить адрес DNS-сервера на роутере

Tags: dns, роутер

Недавно захотелось попробовать сменить дефолтный DNS роутера (Ericsson) на гугловский. Не смог найти меню настроек DNS, может ли их вообще не быть?

Comment: А мануал на роутер у вас есть?

Comment: @0xdb, нет. Роутер не мой, устанавливал (давал в аренду) Ростелеком

Comment: "может ли их вообще не быть?" - вряд ли. Если не найдёте, поставте -[dd-wrt](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).